# Gmail iOS App uses custom html tags - any info?

Tags: html, ios, gmail

So I was looking through the Gmail iOS App (2.0.1) and saw some included html files like calendar.html:

```
<h1>
<?cs #trans description Title for screen in welcome sequence describing the
ability to immediately act on calendar events. (Maximum characters: ~25) ?>
Instantly RSVP</h1>
<p>
<?cs #trans description
Reference to being able to receiving emails for calendar events and being able
to act on the events immediately.
(Maximum characters: ~100 depends on line breaks) ?>
Respond to Google Calendar invites right from the app.
</p>
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what the ?cs tags were for. I did try googling it but I couldn't find anything. Maybe its an internal google thing? Any info would be nice. I'm just trying to learn about iOS/Google programming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<? … ?>` is an XML [processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi). They are not document data, but are intended for the underlying XML engine.

Typically processing instructions are used by an XML engine as a way of embedding control flow (`<? if test="condition" ?>`) and commands (`<? echo "string" ?>`) into the XML document.

Here it looks like `cs` is a kind of meta command. `cs #trans description` appears to be a label for for some kind of user help.

I'm sorry it doesn't directly answer your question, but a better understanding of the form might help you learn more about the function.

Comment: Thank you - I don't have much experience with XML so I was not aware of this. I was thinking it was something like php with its tags. Time to read about XML :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that those bits of text inside the `<?cs>` tag are used during development by an internal Google localization tool to explain the purpose of the following text to a translator. They are probably not displayed or used anywhere in the running application.